# Comandos uteis para .Htacess

Tags: htaccess

Gostaria de saber alguns comandos para utilizar no .htacess que permitam fazer as seguintes ações.

1- Bloquear acesso a todas os diretórios de forma que  caso o usuário tente ver o conteúdo deste diretório seja barrado com um aviso ou redirecionamento para uma pagina.

2- Bloquear o download de arquivos .php, .js, .css, .html e de imagens.

3 - abrir um arquivo que não seja index.php como pagina index

Se possível se poderem me indicar outros comandos uteis isso iria me ajudar muito.

Comment: Fazer isso com o `htaccess` faria com que seu site fosse inútil, pois arquivos de imagens, css e js são baixados para o computador do usuário junto com o HTML para que ele possa visualizar seu site. Pra isso você precisaria tratar no PHP todas as requisições, inclusive de js, css, img e etc...

Answer (score 1):

**1 - Impedindo a listagem de diretórios:**

`Options -Indexes`

**2 - o próprio servidor impede o download de PHP, mas js, css e html rodam do lado do cliente, se impedir seu download, ninguém verá o seu site.**

**3 - Para definir as páginas iniciais padrão use:**

`DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.html`

por exemplo para definir empresa.html:

`DirectoryIndex empresa.html`